# IOException: AsyncTask Image Download Kotlin Android (Bad File Descriptor)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kotlin

**UPDATE**

After some debugging, I find out that
Catch block in given code get executed without any exception exception.
I print inputstream which return some value, event bitmap varibale gets initialised but once it executed catch block, it return null to onPostExecute method.

Searching out why it is happening ?

[Please check debug screenshot of studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW9Jt.png)

**END**

I am using Android Studio 3.0.

Created simple android application with Kotlin Support, which download image from give http protocol url with help of AsyncTask class and HTTPURLConnection class.

On execution of AsyncTask class, I am getting http response code 200 from HTTPURLConnection object but while decoding stream with BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputstream) method throws IOEXception.

StackTrace tends to error Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: EBADF , on same line where calling this BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputstream) method.

```
    override fun doInBackground(vararg args: String?): Bitmap? {

    var bitmap: Bitmap? = null

    try {

        val url = URL(args[0])
        val connection: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

        connection.requestMethod = "GET"
        connection.connectTimeout = 10 * 60 * 60
        connection.readTimeout = 10 * 60 * 60
        connection.doInput = true
        connection.doOutput = true

        connection.connect()
        val responseCode = connection.responseCode
        if (HTTP_OK == responseCode) {
            if (null != connection.inputStream) {
                val inputStream = connection.inputStream
                connection.disconnect()
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
            }
        }else{
            Log.e("####","Error Response Code: ${responseCode}")
        }

    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        Log.e("####",ex.localizedMessage)

    } catch (ex: MalformedURLException) {
        ex.printStackTrace()

    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()

    }

    return bitmap
}
```

Comment: `connection.disconnect()` I would not do that if i wanted to read from the stream yet.

Comment: I have already collected inputstream reference : before disconnect line
but even after removing  connection.disconnect() still i am getting same error.

Comment: `connection.doOutput = true` Remove that statement. It´s for POST.

Comment: URL i am using : http://controltech.biz/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Free-Service-Call.jpg

Comment: @geenapps:  still same issue

Comment: did you try to write your `inputStream` content? and see whats inside?

Comment: pskink means: read from the input stream yourself (instead of letting BitmapFactory do that) and write the contents to file. Then inspect the file.

Comment: and you dont have to write everything: write for example first 32 bytes, so what do you have if you run `hexdump -C` or any similar tool?

Comment: so what do you have in the first 32 bytes of your `InputStream`?

Comment: `I print inputstream which return some value`. ??? What is 'printing an input stream'? And where and how is a value returned? And what was the value? Please adapt your post so we know what you do.

Comment: This is partial output as it is image file

11-09 20:43:05.303 24888-24982/com.example.ganeshtikone.kotlinasync 
E/ImageDownloaderAsyncTask: ������JFIF������d��d��������Ducky����������d������XICC_PROFILE������HLino����mntrRGB XYZ ����� ����1����acspMSFT��������IEC

Comment: You should read the whole inputstream. Save all to file and inspect the file. How many bytes?

Comment: the header seems to be ok but greenapps is right: save all the bytes and try to use that file inside `res/drawable` folder

Comment: @pskink : I want to show , image in imageview ,which i am downloading from web and converting to bitmap using BitmapFactory.decodeStream() method. I don't want to save image in file. Storing image in file which is working fine.

Comment: I found work around: 
i wrote return statement after 
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
return bitmap

which returns from function immediately does not execute catch block

Answer (score 1):

You should only call disconnect **after** you already read response body.

Answer (score 1):

It's java, but you can adapt it to Kotlin:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
connection.disconnect()
```

Comment: Use same logic of Java but getting IOException.

Comment: @GaneshTikone On which line? Post stacktrace

Comment: @ Florescu George Cătălin: Updated question, Catch block get executed even there is no exception thrown by code.

Comment: @GaneshTikone what's the error? I don't see any stacktrace in your screenshot. You let code run, then you look into your Logcat after it.